# .xsession ignored, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, xorg, lightdm

I started using uxterm instead of Gnome's terminal today. I put settings for uxterm in `~/.Xdefaults`. But because Ubuntu's configuration ignores my `.xsession` file, I can't have these settings loaded at login. How can I get Unity (or lightdm) to run `.xsession`? My `.xsession` is recognized and run by XMonad.

Comment: BTW, a hack is a `.xprofile` that runs `.xsession`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`~/.xsession` is only used when no X session is selected. Use `~/.xsessionrc` to run programs at startup.

As using `~/.Xdefaults` is obsolete, Ubuntu, like about any other modern X environment,  uses `~/.Xresources` at startup (see for example [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2005/09/msg01385.html) for some reasons). So if you put your settings in `~/.Xresources` you don't need to run `xrdb` as Ubuntu is doing this for you.

See `/etc/X11/Xsession` and `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*` if you want to know more about what Ubuntu is doing when you start a X session.

Comment: Thanks! moving .Xdefaults to .Xresources solved my problem. And thanks again, for other useful tips.

Answer (score -1):

A note: in Ubuntu 12.03 .xsessionrc is also ignored

to solve it:

open

```
./Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc
```

at the beginning, add

```
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
```

this is the final content:

```
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

#Source user defined xsessionrc (locales and other environment variables)
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
if [ -r "$USERXSESSIONRC" ]; then
  . "$USERXSESSIONRC"
fi
```

I don't know if it's solved in versions >12.04